# How can I install the Stack Exchange Auto Comments for Google Chrome?

Tags: support, comments, google-chrome, userscript, external-project

How can I install Auto Comments script for Google Chrome?

The [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc) listed on [GitHub](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments?tab=readme-ov-file) doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The [tag:automatic-comments] tag is for the comments posted by Stack Exchange itself, on behalf of users, not by using any userscript. That is why I removed it, it does not fit here. The question is about external userscript for Google Chrome, that is meant to write comments, and those are the tags that should be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension version of it is no longer supported and no longer available.   You can install my version of it as a Tampermonkey script from https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-comment-templates

It is also listed on Stack Apps: [Comment Templates Context Menu, an auto-comments user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/9426)

Answer (score 9):

The original browser plugin (as mentioned) stopped working when browsers changed how plugins worked. The upside was it was a predecessor of UserScripts (GreaseMonkey, Tampermonkey, etc.), so migrating wasn't hard. You can still download what should be a functional version of the userscript [from the repo](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) (TL;DR [direct userscript install link](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js)).

The repo was unattended for a while, but Benjol (the original author) has added some contributors (such as myself) who are approving pull requests again (Benjol no longer works on the project directly). As Stephen mentioned, there are other script writers as well.